# How to set the network proxy for ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, proxy, json

I have installed shadowsocks, and start it by typing:

```
sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks/config.json -v start
```

If I set network proxy in Automatic method with a ***.pac** file, it works. I can view google, but there are still some sites I cant view.

So I want to set the network proxy manual way.

#### But what exactly should I fill into the box to make it work?

**config.json**

```
{
   "server":"serverip",
   "server_port":serverport,
    "local_address":"127.0.0.1",
    "local_port":1080,
    "password":"passwd",
    "timeout":300,
    "method":"aes-256-cfb",
    "fast_open": false,
    "workers": 1
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your target sites into the pac file.
If your pac file is generated by the genpac,
you should use that to add some user rules, just take a look at its document on github.

```bsh
genpac --format=pac --pac-proxy="SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:1080" --gfwlist-proxy="SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:1080" --user-rule-from="/Where/rules/at/rules.txt" --output="proxy.pac"
```

rules.txt:

```bsh
||bilibili.com
||I-cannot-access-this-directly.com
```

If you do that, `https://bilibili.com` will get accessed through the proxy(gets slower)